# Blazor select onchange event value not changed

Tags: c#, razor, drop-down-menu, blazor-server-side, onchange

I have a `<select>` inside my Razor View. I'm trying to save the selected option in the database whenever the selection is changed.

I'm able to do it with an `<input type="text">` or any type of input, but my select doesn't  work.

Here is the code :

```
<select name="expression@(i)"
@onchange="@(async e =>
{
    // Test is always equals to "1", which is the old value of the select
    var test = e.Value.ToString());
    
    //Do Stuff
})">

@foreach (var expression in (ExpressionEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(ExpressionEnum)))
{
    <option value="@((int)actionItem.ExpressionEnum)" selected=@(expression == actionItem.ExpressionEnum)>
        @expression.ToString()
    </option>
}
</select>
```

As commented, the selected option of the select is actually the first one, "1".

But even if I try to select another one like the "5", the `test` variable will remains equal to "1".

How can I get the correct selected value ?

Comment: How did you check that `test` always equals 1 ?

Comment: with a breakpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`actionItem.ExpressionEnum` does not seem to change during the loop which sets `value` to, what I assume to be, 1 for every option in your `<select>`.

I believe you should change this part:

```
value="@((int)actionItem.ExpressionEnum)"
```

to

```
value="@expression"
```

Comment: That was the issue ! I didn't use the expression var I created specifically for that. Thank you very much !